# Select different column based on condition (CASE?) and get the column name the value is coming from

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a row with this data:

```
id=1, p1=X, p2=Y, p1f=0, p2f=NULL
```

How to select either p1 or p2 based on which p1f or p2f is 0?

I tired:

```
SELECT 
    id, p1, p2,
    CASE
       WHEN p1f = 0 THEN id, p1
       WHEN p2f = 0 THEN id, p2
       ELSE NULL 
    END 
FROM match
```

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

I got the value. Thank you!

...however, I still need to know which column the value is coming from.

i.e. must know whether the column p1 or p1 was selected.

Can this be done in one query at all?

Comment: what if p1f or p2f are both 0 or none are 0?

Comment: there is no such case :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move `id` out of the `case`:

```
SELECT
    id
,   CASE WHEN p1f=0 THEN p1 WHEN p2f=0 then p2 ELSE NULL END as p
,   CASE WHEN p1f=0 THEN 'p1' WHEN p2f=0 then 'p2' ELSE NULL END as p_name
FROM match
```

This assumes that the type of `p1` and `p2` is the same. If the two columns have different types, you need to add a cast of one or both to some common type.

Note that if you wanted more columns to be selected based on the same condition you would have to repeat the condition in multiple separate `CASE`s.

Comment: Thank you.  It works but I had to add:WHERE p1f=0 OR p2f=0

Comment: Is there a way to get the column name the value is coming from?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close:

```
SELECT id,
       (CASE WHEN p1f = 0 THEN p1
             WHEN p2f = 0 THEN p2
        END)
FROM match;
```

A `case` *expression* only returns one value.

Comment: Thank you! Yours work too after adding WHERE clause. Otherwise it selects all record not only the ones where the condition is met

Comment: his answer is pretty much correct based on what you have asked, you never mentioned any WHERE condition in your question. I would say the answer does not cover ELSE too

Comment: @igigi . . . What `where` condition?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Thanks you!  I asked :"How to select either p1 or p2 based on which p1f or p2f is 0?"  So without WHERE clause it gives me all entries and not only the where p1f or p2f  is 0.  Anyway, i got that solved and you was very helpful. Thanks